# Target is not bind to automatic variable in Makefile job expanded by macro

Tags: makefile, sh

I'm trying to write jobs that contain a lot of similarities as below.

```
EMACS_VERS     := 22.1 23.4 24.5 25.3 26.1
LOCAL_LISPDIRS := $(patsubst %,local/%/site-lisp,$(EMACS_VERS))

$(addsuffix /leaf, $(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)): site-lisp/leaf
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$(@F) $@
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(dir $(@D)) .make-repo-$(@F)

$(addsuffix /orglyth, $(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)): site-lisp/orglyth
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$(@F) $@
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(dir $(@D)) .make-repo-$(@F)

$(addsuffix /cort, $(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)): site-lisp/cort
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$(@F) $@
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(dir $(@D)) .make-repo-$(@F)
```

However, when those job was expanded by below macro, the target name was not bind to the automatic variable, and an error occurred.

```
define build_repo
$1: $2
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$(@F) $@
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(dir $(@D)) .make-repo-$(@F)
endef

$(eval $(call build_repo,$(addsuffix /leaf,$(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)),site-lisp/leaf))
$(eval $(call build_repo,$(addsuffix /orglyth,$(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)),site-lisp/orglyth))
$(eval $(call build_repo,$(addsuffix /cort,$(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)),site-lisp/cort))
```

The above code gets the following error. As I think, this happens because the name of the target is not an automatic variable bound.

```
mkdir -p
usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory ...
make: *** [Makefile:72: local/22.1/site-lisp/leaf.el] Error 64
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

On the other hand, the following code has been rejected as changes to leaf, orglyth, cort are all generated when change files in only leaf.

```
REPOS       := leaf orglyth cort
REPODIRS    := $(addprefix site-lisp/, $(REPOS))
LOCAL_REPOS := $(foreach repo, $(REPOS), $(addsuffix /$(repo), $(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)))
$(LOCAL_REPOS): $(REPODIRS)
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$(@F) $@
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $(dir $(@D)) .make-repo-$(@F)
```

Directory tree:

```
local
├── 22.1
│   └── site-lisp
│       ├── cort
│       ├── leaf
│       └── orglyth
├── 23.4
│   └── site-lisp
│       ├── cort
│       ├── leaf
│       └── orglyth
├── 24.5
│   └── site-lisp
│       ├── cort
│       ├── leaf
│       └── orglyth
├── 25.3
│   └── site-lisp
│       ├── cort
│       ├── leaf
│       └── orglyth
└── 26.1
    └── site-lisp
        ├── cort
        ├── leaf
        └── orglyth
site-lisp
├── cort
├── leaf
└── orglyth
```

Comment: Your macro is expanded twice. Double all `$` signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro is expanded twice. Double all `$` signs to escape the first expansion.

As you have two nested loops (versions and repos) it would be difficult to use pattern rules instead of macros. But you can probably use macros a bit more efficiently:

```
# $(1): repo
# $(2): version
define build_repo
local/$(2)/site-lisp/$(1): site-lisp/$(1)
    mkdir -p $$(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$$(@F) $$@
    $$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $$(dir $$(@D)) .make-repo-$$(@F)
endef
$(foreach r,$(REPOS),$(foreach v,$(EMACS_VERS),$(eval $(call build_repo,$(r),$(v)))))
```

Or:

```
# $(1): repo
# $(2): version
define build_repo
local/$(2)/site-lisp/$(1): site-lisp/$(1)
    mkdir -p local/$(2)/site-lisp
    cp -rf site-lisp/$(1) local/$(2)/site-lisp/$(1)
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C local/$(2) .make-repo-$(1)
endef
$(foreach r,$(REPOS),$(foreach v,$(EMACS_VERS),$(eval $(call build_repo,$(r),$(v)))))
```

The second version does not need any `$` escape because everything is correctly and completely expanded at the first expansion. Yes, even `$(MAKE)` that, most likely in your case, expands the same during the first or the second expansion.

But remember that this is a special case. If you continue using the `$(eval...)` function do not forget the double expansion...

Comment: Awesome!!
Your code worked perfectly, and I think it's a very smart code!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Renaud Pacelet for your good reply!

```
define build_repo
$1: $2;
    mkdir -p $$(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$$(@F) $$@
    $$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $$(dir $$(@D)) .make-repo-$$(@F)
endef

$(call build_repo,$(addsuffix /leaf,$(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)),site-lisp/leaf)
$(call build_repo,$(addsuffix /orglyth,$(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)),site-lisp/orglyth)
$(call build_repo,$(addsuffix /cort,$(LOCAL_LISPDIRS)),site-lisp/cort)
```

With this code I got what I wanted without error. But is there a smarter another way to not use macros?

[Additional notes]

I looked at the answer of @Renaud Pacalet and reconcidered.

Actually, when repositories are changed, I have to build on all versions, so I can do one loop as follows.

```
LOCALDIRS := $(addprefix local/, $(EMACS_VERS))

define build_repo
$(addsuffix /site-lisp/$(1), $(LOCALDIRS)): $(LISPDIR)/$(1)
    mkdir -p $$(@D)
    cp -rf site-lisp/$$(@F) $$@
    $$(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $$(dir $$(@D)) .make-repo-$$(@F)
endef
$(foreach repo, $(REPOS), $(eval $(call build_repo,$(repo))))
```